# How can I autofocus using Javascript on newly created element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one `input` field, if the user hits <kbd>enter</kbd> then it'll be disabled and another one created and so on. I want to autofocus the new `input` field every time I create it, and remove the blue border that's created when I click on it.

If you didn't understand me, see [this link](https://zeyadetman.github.io/ZeeTerminal/).

Comment: After you create the new element, use `newElement.focus()` to focus on it.

Comment: If you don't want a blue border around the focused element, use CSS to change that.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks so much :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **jQuery**'s [`.focus()`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) event to target the newly created `input`.

To remove the blue border, remove the `outline` from the `input` on `:focus` using **CSS**:

```
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only focus on one element at a time.

Comment: I don't think he wants to focus on multiple elements at the same time. He wants to focus on successive elements as he creates them.